# Map is not displaying correctly in android MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I am showing using MapView but when I change view using methods

```
map_view.setStreetView(true);
map_view.setSatellite(false);
```

My map shows white square boxes on map.like

[image]

I am not getting why it is happening? 
Any idea, please Help.

My XML Layout is

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:apiKey="0zkSIDXrbRRAbgiBkpRyxVR-5WWN6Jce_Sed6AQ"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_height="40dip" android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingBottom="0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/ttitle_bar">

                <RadioGroup android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/rgMap" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:checkedButton="@+id/rbtnMapSetManualLocOnMap">
                    <RadioButton android:layout_width="100dip"
                        android:layout_height="30dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                        android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/rbtnMapSetManualLocOnMap"
                        android:button="@drawable/radio_selector_map" />
                    <TextView android:layout_width="2dip"
                        android:layout_height="30dip" />

                    <RadioButton android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                        android:layout_marginRight="0dip" android:layout_width="100dip"
                        android:layout_height="30dip" android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/rbtnSetteliteSetManulaLocOnMap" android:button="@drawable/radio_selector_setellite" />
                    <TextView android:layout_width="0.5dip"
                        android:layout_height="30dip" />

                    <RadioButton android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                        android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="30dip"
                        android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/rbtnHybridSetManulaLocOnMap"
                        android:button="@drawable/radio_selector_hybrid" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

EDIT 
I have used three RadioButton which swithces views.Actually I wanted to change view to Hybrid view,Map view and Satellite view.

So my method for changing view is

```
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (checkedId)
        {
        case R.id.group_purchasing_on_map_radiobtn_map:
             map_view.setStreetView(true);
            map_view.setSatellite(false);
            break;
        case R.id.group_purchasing_on_map_radiobtn_hybrid:
             map_view.setStreetView(true);
            map_view.setSatellite(true);
            break;
        case R.id.group_purchasing_on_map_radiobtn_satellite:
             map_view.setStreetView(false);
             map_view.setSatellite(true);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post code, xml layout....etc.

Comment: check this in Android Device ...I think screen shots is Emulator

Comment: did you set some zoom level ? If then try to reduce and check !

Comment: @bugfinder Yes I have also tried by setting zoom level.

Comment: Try reducing that zoom level..Because when the zoom level is high, map can't identify some places(especially street which is not well known)

Comment: @bugfinder I have tried doing that too.

Comment: @AB1209, Please provide the layout file code here.